# Изменить класс соседнего с чекбоксом элемента

Tags: checkbox, javascript, html

Нужно изменить класс соседнего с чекбоксом элемента при клике (выделении) по чекбоксу, при условии, что у чекбокса есть только класс, и выполнить нужно без jquery.

Код html:

```
<div class="post">
<input type="checbox" class="check">
<p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Весь блок создается с помощью js посредством

```
var div= document.createElement('div');
div.className='post';
....
```

и так далее,  после чего аппендится в нужное место на странице.

До меня не доперает, как повесить на него обработчик событий, либо я просто этого не знаю, т. к. в нативном js еще слаб.

Впоследствии предполагаю сделать что-то вроде

```
this.sibligs.className+='new_class';
```

Правильно ли это? Если нет, то как будет лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте событие [change](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp). При прямом измемении имени класса не забывайте про пробел между именами или используйте [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: да благодарю разобрался. ответ ниже тоже весьма полезен. блгодарю

Answer (score 1):

CSS-мастера обычно решают проблему по-другому:

```
input.check:checked + p {
    ...
}
```

этот селектор совпадет с элементом, следующим за input с классом check, у которого проставлена галка.